Managing concurrency of "Execute Pipeline"-activities
I have trouble setting up a parent pipeline in Azure Data Factory. The pipeline should only run 4 child pipelines at once however when starting the pipeline it seems to run all child pipelines at once.
Current setup:

A pipeline which does trigger 16 other pipelines through "Execute Pipeline"-Activities
Each child pipeline has some logic to it and does trigger a databricks notebook
Each child pipeline can run concurrrently to the other pipelines
Due to the activity limit and visibility each logic is in its child pipeline (cannot be combined in parent pipeline)

Wanted setup:

Run max 4 child pipelines concurrently to avoid overloading the systems

Additionally is there a way to monitor queue times of the child pipelines? In our connected Log Analytics I was unable to find a relevant attribute.


The pipeline should only run 4 child pipelines at once however when starting the pipeline it seems to run all child pipelines at once

One of the reasons for this could be not checking the Wait on completion checkbox in the Execute pipeline activities. By checking this, the activity will wait till the completion of the current pipeline run and won't start the next activity in the pipeline flow. So, make sure you check this in the Execute pipeline activity.


Run max 4 child pipelines concurrently to avoid overloading the systems

As you want to run all 16 pipelines from parent pipeline, you can try the below pipeline design in the parent pipeline to achieve your requirement.

You can change the dependency to after the completion of the activity instead of On success as per your requirement.
In this way, at every time, there will be only 4 child pipeline runs from the parent pipeline.

Sorry for getting back to you so late. What I initially thought of is 16 pipelines without any connection to each other so 4 pipelines can run whenever only limited by the concurrency limit. As I understand it is not possible?

If you do like that, I think all the execute pipeline activities will start at same time as those activities flow is in parallel.

Yes, thats what I have observed even though concurrency is limited to 4.

I guess there would be some kind of workaround with a foreach-activity to get it working the way I want but thats not very maintainable. Sadly there are to many workaround you have to do with ADF.

Execute pipeline activity doesn't have dynamic expression for the pipeline name. So, even though you use a for-each to execute each child pipeline, you cannot dynamically call each child pipeline. You still need to use same number of execute pipeline activities as same as child pipelines which is same as above issue.
